# Oracle SQL Query - where clause starting and end in certain values

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to check whether my query is correct. I have written a simple query on one table and against a field in that table where we are looking for all rows where the value in that field is starting with a certain characters and ending in certain characters, but must not contain certain characters in that field's value. Thus -

```
           WHERE field_1 LIKE 'ABC%' AND field_1 LIKE '%XWY' AND field_1 NOT LIKE '%GHI12XY%'
```

The result is no rows, which is what we wanted, but I am not 100% sure whether the query is spot on and would like other whether this is correct

Comment: In the question you said "starting with a certain characters" - what does that mean? "**a**" means a single one; "character**s**" means several. (Yes, sometimes grammar does have meaning, and it is relevant to the question!) Moreover, your query attempt seems to suggest that you are looking for values that begin with a given ***substring***, not with one particular character, or one of a list of characters. Do you really mean "substring" everywhere? If so, then the query is correct.

Comment: So basically I could have a string like ABC_GHI12XY_XWY, and what I want to do is find any string start with ABC, and ending with XWY, but what I don't want is any string that contains or includes GHI12XY. I cannot say that simply returning any rows NOT LIKE GHI12XY and there could rows not starting with ABC and XWY. So, the specific thing all 3 parts are crucial

Comment: OK, so that is a string that begins with the *substring* ABC, etc. Your solution is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me. A good idea in all database software development is to create and load one or more test tables with rows that can be used to verify your logic. Then run your query against the test table(s) and see if you get the results you expect. Ideally, the rows in your test table will cover all the possibilities, for example, where you're supposed to get output, and where you're not supposed to get any.